# Burninate the [cisco] tag

Tags: discussion, status-declined, burninate-request

The [cisco](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cisco) tag falls under the same category as [apple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple), [microsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft), and other company names. Can we burninate it?

For reference:

#### Is this on topic?

Maybe, but a good number of the questions it draws belong on Network Administration SE, Server Fault, or Super User instead.

#### Does it unambiguously describe the content?

No, there are lots of Cisco products, so the fact that the question is about *some* Cisco product isn't at all unambiguous.

#### Does it add any meaningful information to the post?

No, if people tag their questions with the specific product that they're actually using (which they should do anyway) this is completely redundant.

#### Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

Technically, yes.

Comment: More than a few of those belong on [NetworkEngineering.SE](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/) (and not on Server Fault)

Comment: @Machavity True - it seems like a low-quality-question magnet.

Comment: Don't remove something because it looks like other tags; don't remove something because it's a symptom of a problem; remove it [because it causes problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate).

Comment: @Shog9 I edited to describe why I think it meets the criteria to be burned. The tag is worthless *at best* IMHO (and is arguably actively harmful if it draws off topic questions).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Worth observing the description of [the cisco tag on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/tags/cisco/info):

> Cisco is a provider of switches and routers to commercial consumers. Cisco devices run IOS or NX-OS operating systems. This is a generic tag to be used when no more specific tags are available. See the partial list of tags in the full Tag Wiki.

This is pretty good advice; we should probably consider adopting it, given the current tag wiki makes no mention at all of the [cisco-ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cisco-ios) tag or any other more specialized tags.

This also highlights a bit of a problem with trying to disambiguate the tag: there are a lot more specific Cisco products than there are Cisco-related tags. And many of the questions appear to use the tag only as a rough filter on their context, since the specifics aren't particularly relevant anyway. If you were going to go through these retagging them, you'd want to have a pretty solid idea of what Cisco's software environment looks like (I don't).

With 590 tagged questions (for comparison, the google tag had something like 11 thousand), many of them off-topic, I don't see a whole lot of value in focusing on the tag here - at worst, it's slightly less specific than it could be; at best, it at least provides a little bit of extra context.

I recommend trying to come up with some better guidance for the folks using the tag and then cleaning up the most blatantly off-topic questions in it.

Comment: It does seem like a bit of a bad question magnet, though... incidentally, I really do wish that new users would read the help center and tag usage guide.

Comment: "bad question magnet" isn't a thing, @EJoshuaS. Or at the very least, it is an inversion of causality. Tags are filled in *last*, not first. Nobody peruses the list of tags to see if their question is on-topic. They just ask it, and pick whichever tags seem relevant. If there is nothing relevant, they'll pick *irrelevant* tags. Seen it many times.

Comment: @CodyGray I have seen plenty of cases where the OP used the fact that other people have asked similar questions as evidence that their question is on topic, though, so there is a broken windows effect.

Comment: Folks make all kinds of excuses, @EJoshuaS. If there's a broken window, it's almost certainly the scores of off-topic *questions*, not the tag.

Comment: That's probably largely true (@CodyGray does bring up a good point about people not tagging until the end), but given that newbies don't necessarily read the tag descriptions too carefully it's completely possible that the mere presence of the tag will be taken as evidence that the questions are on-topic. For example, we have a [project-management] tag (even though all project management questions are off-topic here); if you didn't read the help center or tag description, you could easily assume that the fact that we have that tag means that that is, in fact, on topic.

Comment: Not all project management questions are off-topic. I've answered several about managing projects in Visual Studio. (Although the [tag:projects-and-solutions] tag also exists for that. I'm not sure why that is better.) Sometimes it seems that people turn off their brains when evaluating tags and forget that they're meant to be interpreted in the context of a *programming* Q&A site.

Comment: I am curious (and I'm not sure how we'd settle that statistically) whether tags had fewer (either in absolute terms or proportionally) new off-topic questions after a cleanup effort - if there was a way to find that out, it seems like it would be evidence as to how much of the "broken windows" effect is due to the existence of other off-topic questions. I'd expect that after a completed cleanup effort the amount of the decrease would tell you how strong the broken windows effect was.